# How can I style last row using jsPDF Autotable plugin?

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I create a PDF document based on a table using `jsPDF` and `AutoTable`:

```
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
   //columns and rows are arrays created from the table content
        doc.autoTable(columns, rows, {

        drawRow: function (row) {
            if (row.index == rows.length - 1) {
                console.log('last row');
                //TODO
            }
        },
        pageBreak: 'avoid',
        headerStyles: {
            fillColor: [239, 154, 154],
            textColor: [0, 0, 0],
            halign: 'center'
        },
        bodyStyles: {
            halign: 'center'
        },
        margin: {top: 60},
        theme: 'striped'
    });

    doc.save('table.pdf');
```

What I'm trying to do is setting a different background color for the last table row. As shown in the code above, I can detect when the last row is being drawn, however I can't manage to modify it. I have tried setting the `row.fillColor` using an RGB value, which seems to have no effect.

I also took a look at the [examples](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable/blob/master/examples/examples.js), but couldn't find anything that could help me on that issue. Any ideas?

Comment: I assume you created the `jspdf-autotable` tag. Thanks!

Comment: @SimonBengtsson yes I did, since I was a bit of angry that google search for my issue haven't lead me to a ton of SO posts ;) Such a useful stuff as your AutoTable plugin kinda deserves more popularity imo

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To change styles dynamically you have two options. The first is to use `didParseCell` to change autoTable styles:

```
doc.autoTable({
    html: '#table',
    didParseCell: function (data) {
        var rows = data.table.body;
        if (data.row.index === rows.length - 1) {
            data.cell.styles.fillColor = [239, 154, 154];
        }
    }
});
```

The second is to use `willDrawCell` if you'd rather use jspdf styling functions:

```
doc.autoTable({
    html: '#table',
    willDrawCell: function (data) {
        var rows = data.table.body;
        if (data.row.index === rows.length - 1) {
            doc.setFillColor(239, 154, 154);
        }
    },
});
```

See more advanced examples [here](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable/blob/a35c7a2c18ba4a8f10a7fb420335c05b8824524a/examples/examples.js#L319).

Answer (score 6):

It has been almost three years since the last response to this question. 
I was struggling a bit to achieve that effect with drawCell function.
In `jspdf-autotable": "^3.0.10"` you should use one of three following callbacks to achieve what you want:

```
    // Use to change the content of the cell before width calculations etc are performed
    didParseCell: function (data) {
    },
    willDrawCell: function (data) { 
    },
    // Use to draw additional content such as images in table cells
    didDrawCell: function (data) {
    },
```

In your case `willDrawCell` is the one you want to use.
So the code will be something like:

```
doc.autoTable({
  columns,
  body,
  headStyles: {
    fillColor: "#0d47a1"
  },
  willDrawCell: drawCell
});

let drawCell = function(data) {
  var doc = data.doc;
  var rows = data.table.body;
  if (rows.length === 1) {
  } else if (data.row.index === rows.length - 1) {
    doc.setFontStyle("bold");
    doc.setFontSize("10");
    doc.setFillColor(255, 255, 255);
  }
};
```